# How can I reduce view calls on Couchbase?

Tags: php, database, mapreduce, couchbase

Now I have a pretty big set of analytics, each in it's own document . I run a map/reduce that reduces them to a aggregated set like this :

Takes a start key and end key (time start and time end) and returns the following

```
 {"apps":{"unknown":6,"Samsung Gear":2},"countries":{"united states":6,"canada":1,"Mexico":1},"ratings":2,"rates":3,"total_count":8}}
```

Now the problem is say I was to get data for 7 days after each other . If I provide a Start (7days ago) and (today) I get one aggregated array - so I am forced to query 7 times , with the start and end of each day. Is there any better way to construct the map reduce?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use range queries ( provide startKey / endKey ) if you want to select a range of dates, if you are storing time stamps as unix time for example.

http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-querying.html

Comment: I am using a time stamp , however the start and end key are for one iteration , while I want to pass for example 7 iterations

Example :
Start 1 End 7

What I want :
1-2 2-3 3-4 4-5 5-6 6-7